# Pretty print exported keyboard configuration file

Tags: python, shortcut

There's a list of common Blender keyboard shortcuts [Common Shortcuts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/keymap/introduction.html)
Before making changes to that with my own custom shortcuts I wanted to see the shortcuts list.

Before I re-invent the wheel, is it possible to pretty print the exported keyboard configuration python file from Blender so it's human readable?

For example, for text jump we have

```
...
("Text Generic",
    {"space_type": 'TEXT_EDITOR', "region_type": 'WINDOW'},
    {"items":
    [("text.start_find", {"type": 'F', "value": 'PRESS', "ctrl": True}, None),
    ("text.jump", {"type": 'J', "value": 'PRESS', "ctrl": True}, None),
...
```

In the preferences it looks like this

[image: keyboard shortcut text jump]

So I'd like to print out:

```
TEXT

Text Generic

Jump  Ctrl J
```

But for all of the values and keys (pun intended)

Comment: There used to be an addon that created SVG layouts https://github.com/blender/blender-addons-contrib/blob/master/system_keyboard_svg.py

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to work with 2.9. grease pencil is causing an issue `Warning: TypeError('bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "" not found in (\'OBJECT\
', \'EDIT\', \'POSE\', \'SCULPT\', \'VERTEX_PAINT\', \'WEIGHT_PAINT\', \'TEXTURE
_PAINT\', \'PARTICLE_EDIT\', \'EDIT_GPENCIL\', \'SCULPT_GPENCIL\', \'PAINT_GPENC
IL\', \'VERTEX_GPENCIL\', \'WEIGHT_GPENCIL\')')`